# Subqueries structure issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, nested, subquery, aggregate

I'm new to SQL and I've been having trouble putting together this query,
the table that I have is like this

```
[ItemID] [int] 
[ItemName] [varchar](50) 
[ItemType] [varchar](50) 
[Original_Price] [money] 
[Retail_Price] [money] 
[MonthlySales] [int] 
[YearlySales] [int]
```

I need to find the profit made Monthly and Yearly on 'WaterBottle' which is under ItemName

I tried this but I keep getting errors and I know it the way I'm putting it together but I'm not sure how to do it the right way.

```
    SELECT  [Profit] * [MonthlySales] AS MonthlySales,
    SELECT  [Profit] * [YearlySales] AS YearlySales,
    ITEM
        (
        SELECT      SUM([Retail_Price]-[Original_Price]) AS Profit, ItemName
        FROM        Menu
        WHERE ItemName = 'WaterBottle '
        GROUP BY    ItemName
        )
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will give you the result you want

```
 SELECT SUM((Retail_Price-Original_Price) * MonthlySales) AS MonthlySales1,
        SUM((Retail_Price-Original_Price) * YearlySales) AS YearlySales1
            FROM   Menu
            WHERE ItemName = 'WaterBottle '
            GROUP BY ItemName
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the need for a subquery here. Is it not as simple as:

```
SELECT  
    SUM([Retail_Price] - [Original_Price]) * SUM([MonthlySales]) AS MonthlySales,
    SUM([Retail_Price] - [Original_Price]) * SUM([YearlySales]) AS YearlySales
FROM
    Menu
WHERE
    ItemName = 'WaterBottle';
```